# How to get pdf base64 data from httpwebresponse rest api

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am getting a PDF using HttpWebResponse. I have copied the response stream to a memory stream and converted the stream data to base64 using a byte array. I then save the base64 string to a database. When the PDF contains plain text it is working fine.  I have tried like

```
using (HttpWebResponse responsePdf = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream stream = responsePdf.GetResponseStream();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    base64PdfData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

    stream.Close();
}
```

If PDF contains images or highlighted contents, then I don't receive the correct base64 string and the PDF doesn't open.

How can I get the PDF data?

Response Headers

```
content-type: application/pdf
content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"
```

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow Ajay! could you be more specific about *"correct base64 string is not coming?"* have you tried to dump the response into file directly without converting it to base64 and see if it a valid (can be opened) pdf file?

Comment: The pdf should have an ascii header.  Open pdf with notepad and see if you can detect the header.